Sufficient conditions for the extrema of a functional to occur at constant functions
I'm doing some work in physics and it came to my attention that a useful result would require me to justify that a functional of the form:
$$S(x)=\int_{T}[F(x)\cdot(1- \lambda x)+\lambda \dot{x}]dt$$
With $x(t)\geq 0$ for all times $t\in T$, finds its extrema only when $x=c$ with $c\in \mathbb{R}^{+}\cup \{0\}$ . In other words, I would like to know when does an extremum for this functional fulfill the equation of motion: $\dot{x}=xF(x)=0$.
It is trivial to prove that the constraint $x=0$ is a minimum, I am more interested in figuring out the conditions for $c>0$. I've tried using the Euler-Lagrange equation, it yields:
$$\lambda F(x)=(1-\lambda x)\frac{dF(x)}{dx}$$
But I can't easily intuit the sufficient conditions I must impose on $F$ and $\lambda$ in the general case and how these would give me $c>0$

Does $\lambda$ depend on $t$?
